# How to get data from server into Datagridview C#

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio, datagridview

I want to get some Data displayed at a DataGridview.

Here is what I tryed so far :

```
            cn.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select * FROM Arbeiter WHERE (Name Like '%" + tbSuche.Text + "%'", cn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

I get the error :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll

it works without the WHERE part ... so I think the error should be there .

Thanks for your help

Comment: TIP: 'Name' is generally not a very good variable name. It is a reserved keyword in MySQL for instance. Maybe call it WorkerName or something more descriptive. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not close your parenthesis in the sql query. Should be:

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select * FROM Arbeiter WHERE (Name Like '%" + tbSuche.Text + "%')", cn);
```

I always like to put mine on a new line like:

```
string sql = "select * FROM Arbeiter WHERE (Name Like '%" + tbSuche.Text + "%'";
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, cn);
```

That way I can always put in a breakpoint before execution and copy the SQL statement over to SQL Management Studio to run it there to check the results.